# Restoring from backup after jailbreak

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

If I have a back up on iTunes from before I was jailbroken and I wanted to go back to stock IOS, can I restore to that back up from iTunes and be unjailbroken?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That would undo the jailbreak. All you need to do is start the iPhone into recovery mode and then click restore in the option when your iPhone is connected to your Mac or Windows in iTunes/Finder.